# accordion height issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a simple accordion setup, with just two sections. The top, first section collapsed by default with the bottom second one, expanded by default.

I've ran into a problem, the top first section, when expanded has a style set somewhere that's creating a height of '**3791.8px;**' creating this huge vertical white space (my content is only 1000px). I'm not sure where it's coming from as I've searched the default css that was attached to the script and found nothing related. 
*(http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/)*

I've tried defining the height in that specific div, the accordion div, inline, externally - toggling overflow, and every other which way to try to close this white space/override that style from where it's coming from.

**What can I do?**

*This is pretty much all I have implemented (just with my text content);*

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

  <script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $( "#accordion" ).accordion({ active: 1 });

  });

  </script>

<div id="accordion">

<h3><a href="#">Section 1</a></h3>

 <p> Text content </p>

<h3><a href="#">Section 2</a></h3>

<p> Text content </p>

</div>
```

**Link of problem:** http://tinyurl.com/7xn33hb

Comment: Can you include your CSS for the accordion?

Comment: Even better would be a link to the page.

Comment: Sure guys, link added above in the Q.

Comment: What happens if you use `<p>` instead of `<br />`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try setting `autoHeight: false`

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $( "#accordion" ).accordion({ 
        active: 1,
        autoHeight: false
     });
});
```

Comment: The plugin default behavior makes no sense at all. Thanks for the solution +1

Answer (score 1):

By default, it takes the height of the tallest section and makes all of the sections that height. You can change this to only make it the height of it's actual content by setting the autoHeight property to false. e.g.

```
$( "#accordion" ).accordion({ active: 1, autoHeight: false });
```

Answer (score 0):

By default, jQuery UI's accordion widget sets the [autoHeight](http://jqueryui.com/demos/accordion/#option-autoHeight) option to true. Per the documentation:

> If set, the highest content part is used as height reference for all other parts. Provides more consistent animations.

Set it to `false`, like so:

```
$( "#accordion" ).accordion({ active: 1, autoHeight: false });
```

That will get you the behavior you want.

Comment: I think the confusion is that the documentation link you provide actually talks about heightStyle rather than autoHeight, i.e the documentation is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Just set your `autoheight to "false"`